# Parse enum skipping Obsolete

Tags: c#, generics, enums

How to skip obsolete values when I'm casting my int values to enums? I have minimum working example below:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int valueInt = 1;
        var en = (TestObsolete)valueInt;
        Console.WriteLine(en);
    }
}

enum TestObsolete
{
    Undefined,
    [Obsolete]
    ValueA = 1,
    ValueB=1,
}
```

I'm getting ValueA, but expecting to get ValueB. Especially I'm interested in generic method with following signature:

```
public static T ParseEnumWithoutObsolete<T>(int val) where T: struct {
```

I tried to do something like that:

```
T @enum;
var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>();
var obsoleteValues = enumValues.Where(a => typeof(T).GetField(a.ToString()).CustomAttributes.Any(t => t is ObsoleteAttribute));
var activeValues = enumValues.Except(obsoleteValues);
```

but stuck in the next step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm getting ValueA, but expecting to get ValueB.

You're getting the value represented by the integer 1. The fact that you're *seeing* that as `ValueA` has nothing to do with `Parse`, and everything to do with `ToString`.

It's really, really important to bear in mind that when you have a value of an enum type, it's really just an integer. There can be several names for the same integer value, and they're completely indistinguishable when you've just got the value.

It sounds to me like what you really want to do - possibly in addition to your parsing method - is write a `ToStringWithoutObsolete` method. That could map values to names, but only for values which don't have the obsolete attribute. Note that using `typeof(T).GetField(a.ToString())` anywhere in your code will make the results unpredictable. It would be better to get *all* the static fields within the enum type. So for example:

```
var valueToName = typeof(T)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(f => !f.IsDefined(typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), false))
    .ToDictionary(f => (T) f.GetValue(null),
                  f => f.Name);
```

Comment: OMG, unexpected turn. Let me try to do so

Comment: Just wanted to point out that because multiple enum members can have the same value without being obsolete, this dictionary will not necessarily return every possible non-obsolete name. A more interesting dictionary in that case would be nameToValue.